# Trying to import information from file, but data "might not have been initialized"?

Tags: java, file

As you can see, I am creating a file and reading in the information from it, then assigning that information to variables so I can do things with it. Can someone help me understand why my compiler is saying stuff like deskQuantity, lampPrice, theName, etc. might not have been initialized?

Thank you!

```
/**
Add in javadoc comments
*/


//import statements
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Try2 { 
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //variables
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean valid = false;
        int mainSelect = 0;
        int itemOption = 0;
        boolean valid2 = false;
        boolean returnToMain = false;
        String theName;
        double thePrice;
        int theQuantity;
        double currBal;
        String lampName;
        double lampPrice;
        int lampQuantity;
        String chairName;
        double chairPrice;
        int chairQuantity;
        String deskName;
        double deskPrice;
        int deskQuantity;

        //create file
        try{
            PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("inventory.txt");
            outputFile.println("3000.0");
            outputFile.println("Lamps 15.3 400");
            outputFile.println("Chairs 19.95 250");
            outputFile.println("Desks 95.0 300");
            outputFile.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("File cannot be created.");
        }

        //read data in from file
        try{
            File file = new File("inventory.txt");
            Scanner inFile = new Scanner(file);
            currBal = inFile.nextDouble();
            lampName = inFile.next();
            lampPrice = inFile.nextDouble();
            lampQuantity = inFile.nextInt();
            chairName = inFile.next();
            chairPrice = inFile.nextDouble();
            chairQuantity = inFile.nextInt();
            deskName = inFile.next();
            deskPrice = inFile.nextDouble();
            deskQuantity = inFile.nextInt();
            inFile.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("Cannot find file.");
        }


        //present user with main menu
        do{
        System.out.println("Current Balance: $" + currBal);
        System.out.println("\t1. " + lampName  + "\t\t(" + lampQuantity +  " at $" + lampPrice + ")");
        System.out.println("\t2. " + chairName + "\t\t(" + chairQuantity +  " at $" + chairPrice + ")");
        System.out.println("\t3. " + deskName + "\t\t(" + deskQuantity +  " at $" + deskPrice + ")");
        System.out.println("\t0. Exit");

        while(valid == false){
            System.out.print("\nPlease enter choice: ");
            try{
                mainSelect = kb.nextInt();
                if(0 <= mainSelect || mainSelect >=  3){
                    valid = true;
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("That is not a valid selection. Try again.");
                }
            }
            catch(InputMismatchException ime){
                System.out.println("That is not a valid selection. Try again.");
                kb.next();
            }
        }
        //present user with second menu
        switch(mainSelect){
            case 1:
                theQuantity = lampQuantity;
                thePrice = lampPrice;
                theName = lampName;
                break;
            case 2:
                theQuantity = chairQuantity;
                thePrice = chairPrice;
                theName = chairName;
                break;
            case 3:
                theQuantity = deskQuantity;
                thePrice = deskPrice;
                theName = deskName;
                break;
            case 0:
                System.exit(0);
                break;
        }
        System.out.println("Current balance: $" + currBal);
        System.out.println("Current Quantity: " + theQuantity);
        System.out.println("Current price: $" + thePrice);
        System.out.println("1. Sell " + theName);
        System.out.println("2. Buy " + theName);
        System.out.println("3. Change price");
        System.out.println("0. Return to main menu");

        while(valid2 == false){
            System.out.print("\nPlease enter choice: ");
            try{
                itemOption = kb.nextInt();
                if(0 <= itemOption || itemOption >=  3){
                    valid2 = true;
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("That is not a valid selection. Try again.");
                }
            }
            catch(InputMismatchException ime){
                System.out.println("That is not a valid selection. Try again.");
                kb.next();
            }
        }
    }while(returnToMain == true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to mentally step through the code. What happens if that `catch (FileNotFoundException e)` catches an exception?

Comment: Local variables are not initialised to a default value like instance variables, their default values are undefined.  The compiler is warning you that you may get unexpected results from your code. Try initialising your local variables to a default value first. The `try-catch` blocks make it impossible for the compiler to guarantee that any of your assignments will actually be carried out

Comment: Just as a style point - and not part of an answer to the question, this method is far too long.  It's much easier to find problems in short methods.  You should consider breaking this method down into four or five separate parts.  General rule - you should be able to say in a single sentence what a method does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is warning you that you are trying to use variables that might not have any value.

You create desk quantity like this:

```
int deskQuantity;
```

Then you try to assign it a value (in a try {} block)

```
 try{
            File file = new File("inventory.txt");
            Scanner inFile = new Scanner(file);
            currBal = inFile.nextDouble();
            lampName = inFile.next();
            lampPrice = inFile.nextDouble();
            lampQuantity = inFile.nextInt();
            chairName = inFile.next();
            chairPrice = inFile.nextDouble();
            chairQuantity = inFile.nextInt();
            deskName = inFile.next();
            deskPrice = inFile.nextDouble();
            deskQuantity = inFile.nextInt();
            inFile.close();
        }
```

Then later you print it like this:

```
System.out.println("\t3. " + deskName + "\t\t(" + deskQuantity +  " at $" + deskPrice + ")");
```

But if the try block fails, the value is never set. You can avoid this warning by setting a default value (initializing) the variables like this:

```
String deskName = "";
int deskQuantity = 0;
```

But you should also take care to handle unset values or other failures. You already check to see if the file isn't found. You should also catch other exceptions here and probably stop processing if you catch any:

```
catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    System.out.println("Cannot find file.");
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Caught Exception: " + e.getLocalizedMessage() );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `Scanner inFile = new Scanner(file);` or any of the other lines in the second `try` block throws an exception, then your program catches it, and carries on trying to display the menu.

But the menu code refers to variables that won't have been given values in that case.  The compiler is stopping you from doing this, and forcing you to make sure these variables have values.

It would be best if you moved the menu code up into the second `try` block, so that it won't run if the code that reads the values from the `Scanner` fails.